# How to make Join Query model in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysql-workbench

How to write join query in codeigniter... I want only model like this Select query-

```
public function getData($col, $table, $where = array())
{
        $this->db->select($col);
        $this->db->from($table);
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();

        return $result;
}
```

Plz help

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('blogs');
$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id');
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select
Please go through the user guide before posting it on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```
join query is there..
```

try this

```
$this->db->join('second_table', 'second_table.id = first_table.id');
```

Comment: i want in this format only-

public function getData($col, $table, $where = array())
 {
  $this->db->select($col);
  $this->db->from($table);
  $this->db->where($where);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  $result = $query->result();
  
  return $result;
 }

Comment: $data['item'] = $this->dbmodel->getData('*','catagory',array());

and this would be in controller side.this one is for select query.i want same in join query.how to write ON condition and all

Comment: what will be in the where condition.
where condition will be in $where. Right?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('first_table');
$this->db->join('second_table', 'second_table.col_name = first_table.col_name');
$query=$this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()>0){
return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for joining table you may use join() methods.

```
$this->db->from(table1)
$this->db->join('table2','table1.id=table2.table1_id','join options');
```

on condition means in which condition you want to join tables . 
Join options is optional.
Join Options are: left, right, outer, inner, left outer, and right outer